# Paas free plan for sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, paas

I want to deploy my sails.js application for testing. I don't find sails.js in heroku and openShift node.js support list. Is there Paas free plan for sails.js ?

Comment: Hi Arkar, I did this [screencast](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/11/05/building-a-sails-application-ep26-deploying-a-sails-app-to-heroku/) about deploying to Heroku that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sails project. And use Git to upload to open shift.That's how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a free account with Heroku. (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

You can also create a free sandbox account for MongoDB at https://www.compose.io/.

Takes all of 10 minutes to get it up and running on Heroku for free.